# IOS 8 get pictures off iphone 5 with windows 8

Tags: iphone, ios, windows

Is there some trick to get pictures off an iphone 5 with ios 8 on a Windows 8 computer? I can get my pictures off my iphone 5 with ios 8 on my Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP computer but not my Windows 8 computer. I have tried multiple Windows 8 computers and it won't work on any of them. Yes I know you have to unlock the phone on Windows 8 and I did that.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: @patrix I hooked up my phone to my computer, Opened computer, Iphone doesn't show up in explorer. And of course I unlocked my iphone.

Comment: Does iTunes "see" the phone?

Comment: @patrix How is that relevant? My Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP computers can all see my pictures without itunes.

Comment: Problem solving is all about about verifying potential failure points. If your phone shows up in iTunes on Win8 we can rule out some problem areas (OTOH if it doesn't show up, we can rule out some others).

Comment: @patrix sometimes yes, sometimes no. How does that explain why Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP computers can all see my pictures without itunes and windows 8 can't?

Comment: Win8 might behave differently than the other three versions (and most obviously does)

Comment: @patrix so how does that help me get my pictures with Windows 8? Some Windows 8 computers with itunes can see my phone and some Windows 8 with itunes can't see my phone. I still couldn't get my pictures either way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the iCloud for Windows?

This will connect your Windows PC to your iCLoud account and allow you to save your iCloud photos to a local directory (I believe it's in C:\Users\\Pictures ).

The utility can be found here. https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Untested on Win 8, but here we use Photo Gallery, part of Windows Essentials, to transfer, organise & keep photos on the Win 7 PCs.

It can be set to transfer automatically at connect, & is similar to iPhoto in many respects.

It also saves having to mount the iDevice as an external drive & pick through the folder structure.

Comment: If computer can't see your iphone then Photo Gallery can't see it either.

Comment: Unless the iDevice is set for Disk Use, the 'user desktop' doesn't see it. iTunes, Photo Gallery etc do, as they see it at device-level, not as a mounted desktop drive.

Comment: how do you check if the iDevice is set for Disk Use?

Comment: hmm… apparently that was an iPod option, never available on phones.